# Creating muliple dataframes using a loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, subset, data-cleaning

I am trying to subset my data but I was attempting to do it in a loop and then store those subsets into different dataframes. I have a dataframe named `data` with `20000` variables and I wanted to get sub-sets of that data.

One way of doing it would be for me to use:
`new_1000<-data[,1:1000]`

`new_5000<-data[,1:5000]`

But I wanted to try looping.  The attempt is below, where I was able to subset for the top 1000 `new_1000`. However, I do not know how I can go about to create another dataframe `new_5000`. Edits to this code are welcome.

```
new_1000<-list()
columns <-c(1:1000)
For (i in seq_along(columns)){
new[[i]] <-data[, columns[i]]
}
new_1000<-as.data.frame(new_1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a [list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/17303805) with the first `n_cols` columns:

```
new_dfs <- list()
for (n_cols in c(1000, 5000)) {
  new_dfs[[paste0("new_", n_cols)]] <- data[, seq(n_cols)]
}
```